# MatPlotLib FuncAnimation Sending Function Positional Arguments, 0 needed but 1 given?

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, animation

Having some trouble using MatPlotLib.animation's FuncAnimation. When I send the 'function' parameter, I am given the error message `TypeError: findPrice() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given` where findPrice is the function I'm trying to call. findPrice takes no arguments, but for some reason FuncAnimation seems to be trying to send it one. The actual code follows:

`ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), findPrice, interval=1000)`

I have tried changing `findPrice` to `findPrice()`, but then I get the error message `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`. Any help on how I could solve this positional argument error message? Let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: Please read the docs, in particular the required function signature of *func* kwarg https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html

Comment: If you have a function defined like this def findPrice(data), then place them after its call separated by commas animation.FuncAnimation(fig, findPrice, data_gen,

Answer (score 0):

I've found that adding an argument to your function (eg. findPrice(i) ) fixes the error. No idea as to why but it works